# cannot view ipcamera feed in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to view ip camera feed using UIWebView in my application but I only see a black screen. If I use the same link in Safari on iphone I can view the live feed. Here is the usecase.

When I open the link I am asked to enter login detail. Once I enter them I am taken to another screen where I have to click on "Live Video" link. Now here I see different behavior between safari and UIWebView. On Safari I get a popup which asks the login details again and when I enter that I see the video. But in UIWebView I don't get the popup for login.(UIWebView is one of the tabs in my application) and I only see a black screen.

Any ideas on this issue.

Thanks
Dev.

Answer (score 1):

The alert that asking the username and password is not a default one. You have to make the alert by yourself or you can give the username and password specifically in code when the delegate functions called.

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
    NSURLConnection *myConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [myConn start];

     return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{

        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"userName" password:@"passWord" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forProtectionSpace:[challenge protectionSpace]];

        [myWebView loadRequest:[connection originalRequest]];
}
```